# Not able to import enchant on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, pyenchant, enchant

I have created a different environment for python 3.6.7 32-bit Windows for pyenchant. I have done pip install pyenchant. It was successfully installed. From the command prompt I am able to import the library and also run the example. But when from the same environment, I load the jupyter notebook, and try to import enchant but it gives error : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enchant'**. I have wasted a lot of time trying to fix it. Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer have gave up on supporting pyenchant for windows x64 + python3.5 (here).

The only thing you can do there right now is to try to build it yourself. Or maybe wait until someone steps up as a maintainer of that library.

Here is supporting doc issue for the same:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5816

Hope it helps.